# {Proof Check} Let $x_n$ be a convergent sequence. if $x_n \geq 0$ $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}$ then $\lim x_n \geq 0$

Tags: real-analysis, limits

Please check and point out if there are logical flaws in my argument. I'm learning analysis but I'm not that confident yet.

Proof: Suppose $x_n \geq 0 $ $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}$ and let $\lim x_n = x < 0$. Then $|x| > 0$. Take $\varepsilon = |x|$ then $\exists N \in \mathbb{N}$ s.t. $\forall n \geq N$,

$$|x_n - x| \leq |x_n| + |x| < \varepsilon = |x|$$
$$0 \leq |x_n| = x_n < |x| - |x| = 0$$

This is a contradiction, thus $x \geq 0$.

Comment: Why can you say $|x_n| + |x| < \varepsilon$?

Comment: triangle inequality and $|-x| = |-1||x| = |x|$

Comment: I can see $|x_n - x| \leq |x_n| + |x|$ by the triangle inequality and $|x_n - x| \leq \varepsilon$ given the limit, but not how these give $|x_n| + |x| < \varepsilon$.

Answer (score 2):

You have the right value of $\varepsilon$ (and any value smaller than that but still positive can also serve).

But how did you conclude that $|x_n| + |x|<\varepsilon \text{?}$

I'd write $|x_n-x| = x_n-x$ since $x_n\ge0$ and $-x\ge0,$ and then $x_n-x\ge -x = \varepsilon.$ Thus no matter how big $n$ gets, $|x_n-x|$ never gets less than $\varepsilon.$